# What component to use to navigate between pages like Microsoft Homepage?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

I'm trying to make a header to my website like the header of the Microsoft's website Homepage:
[Microsoft Homepage Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MRNd.png).

The component from Fluent UI that I think is the most similar is the [Pivot](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pivot), but the best practices section says: "Don’t use the Pivot to link to a new page.". And if it's a page from the same website? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm rather sure from looking at the HTML code, that the homepage is not made with Fluent UI and that the header just looks like the Pivot, as you noticed. All the Fluent UI apps made by Microsoft that I'm aware of, don't have a header like this. So maybe the homepage just doesn't follow their own guides.
If I were you and just wanted to have my private homepage look like this, and Pivot would be good enough, then just use it. Only in the context of other Microsoft applications this wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: Update: Just found out that the fluent-ui/react-northstar project has a component like this: https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/components/menu/definition?showCode=false&showRtl=false&showTransparent=false&showVariables=false#types-underlined

Comment: @alex3683 - Did you ever investigate that component further?  It's hard to see if it has a compliment to PivotItem.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I'm not working with react-northstar and just wanted to give the op a hint where he could search further on this topic.